# debugging javascript events to make popovers work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with a lot of Javascript on it. Included is the popular Twitter bootstrap's popover widget which is not working. Specifically if I hover over the icon that should launch the "popover". I know the HTML/JS is correct as it's exactly the same as this working jsfiddle: [simple working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ksnyde/4HxtD/1/).

Here's the HTML inline:

```
   <span id="container">
<i id="common-actions-info" 
    class="icon-info-sign" 
    rel="popover"
    data-trigger='hover'
    data-delay={show:10,hide:500}
    data-placement="right"
    data-title="Common Actions" 
    data-content="A list of actions that you have been using frequently. Choosing any of these actions will open up a new quick entry form to add another of these items."></i>
```

​
And then I connect the popover javascript with:

```
$("[rel=popover]").popover();​
```

In my more complicated "real environment" I can run

> $("[rel=popover]").popover('show/hide')

commands and that works but it's just not getting the signal to display it when I hover over the icon. Anyway, I think the problem is that some other JS is catching the hover events and not triggering the display of the popover.

Is there a good way to use Chrome's debugger to watch DOM events and track down what's happening here?

### UPDATE:

I've been looking at the "Event Listeners" in the Elements tab of Chrome Developer Tools. Although I'm still a little bit overwhelmed with the tree of information it provides I have discerned an important pattern: on pages where the "popover" plugin works you will find a "mouseover" and "mouseout" event listener on the widgets that I guess are responsible for toggle the display of the widget on and off. In a page where it doesn't work these events don't exist (so far what I've seen is that there is no listeners at all).

Does anyone have any idea:

1. what could be conflicting with Bootstraps listeners being setup?
2. how might I troubleshooting this without loosing any more hair on the top of head?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chrome/Firefox plugin called Firebug.

Install it, open it, go to DOM tab and refresh your page. It will show you detailed overview of DOM actions, function executions .... everything.

Take a look at this page: https://getfirebug.com/dom. It will give you a basic functionality of Firebug DOM explorer.

This is also a good tutorial: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-log-dom-events/

**EDIT :**

There's a way you can trap a event. It is not a best solution but it will help you in case some other plugin/framework took control  over needed container:

Lets say you are binding a click event to i#common-actions-info

```
$('i#common-actions-info').click(function() { console.log('clicked!') });
```

You can then use this code to watch what events are bind to i#common-actions-info:

```
var clickEvents = $('i#common-actions-info').data("events").click;
jQuery.each(clickEvents, function(key, handlerObj) {
    console.log(handlerObj.handler) // will print "function() { console.log('clicked!') }"
})
```

Comment: Doesn't the Chrome Developer Tools Timeline tab do something similar?

Comment: I had thought Chrome Developer Tools had completely caught up to Firebug. I use Chrome to debug a lot of things but I'm not sure how to trap events and trace them. This was the main thrust of my question.

Comment: Take a look at my EDIT part, this will trace all events on a needed container. Or have you meant spmething else?

Comment: @gajotres, I did look and I found it helpful but it doesn't solve my problem (although it did show that Firebug has some tricks to it that Chrome doesn't yet). I think what I should do is re-write the question a little as I now have a little more information.